# C# Web Api: How To Get Unique User Device Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So I am implementing an Antiforgery token for my Web Api. So I want to pass a token which contains the encrypted value of the unique user device id, but I do not know how to get the value.

I know `UserAgent` returns the type of the user browser, but it is not a unique value.

Then there is hostname and hostaddress, but these are not unique, also these will be invalid if the user moves to different places (changes the IP address).

I want the token to be valid as long as the user uses the same device no matter where they are.

PS: The token is generated when they are login.

How can I get the "Unique user device id"?

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/a-look-behind-the-jwt-bearer-authentication-middleware-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Try fingerprintJS2 or Panopticlick javascript library.